# How to strip padding (whitespace) from text file when writing dataframe column to file

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

I have a dataframe that I am outputting to a text file (generates database insert statements). I want to align the column to the left and strip all whitespace from the left and right.
I found someone who wrote a function that does this - however, it appears that the resulting outputted file contains a load of padding, whereby the column is padded to the maximum column length:

```
directory = "/dbfs/mnt/testdata/troubleshooting"
filename = "test.txt"

# function to align the columns in the DataFrame to the left
def align_left(s):
    s = s.str.strip()
    return s.str.ljust(s.str.len().max())

data = [[",1,'This is a bit of data in this row'"]
,[",2,'This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row. This is a lot of data in this row.'"]
,[",3,NULL"]
,[",4,'Little bit of data'"]
,[",5,'Tiny bit of data'"]
]
schema = ["TextData"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df_table = df.toPandas()

# use function to align column to left and strip of whitespace
sql_values = df_table.apply(align_left).to_string(header=False, index=False, justify='left')

# remove the characters up to and including the first comma ',' of the string
index = sql_values.find(',')
sql_values = sql_values[index+1:]

sql_values = f"INSERT INTO dbo.table (Id, TextData) \n VALUES({sql_values})"

save_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

# write contents to file
with open(save_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(sql_values)
```

Resulting file:

[image]

The additional spaces more than double the file size. How can I get rid of them? This is what I want the file to look like (all extra spaces removed):

[image]

Comment: `align_left` adds padding. Why are you adding padding if you don't want it?

Comment: Also, I'm not a SQL expert, but I'm pretty sure you should be using a parameterized query here.

Comment: So how can I adjust align_left to remove padding?

Comment: What do you mean? Its entire purpose is to add padding. Did you not realize that?

Comment: clearly not, hence the question. I'm a Python newbie with two weeks experience.

Comment: Sorry, I try not to assume. It wasn't clear what you meant by "align to the left" so I was hoping that was the best way to ask for clarification.

Comment: Please don't put a solution in the question, and especially don't remove important info from the question. Instead, you can [post your own answer](/help/self-answer). I rolled back your edits.

Comment: Although, looking at your solution, [`df.collect()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect) creates a list, but you're already starting with a list, so why do you need a dataframe in the first place? Also, `df_table` is unused.

Comment: Also, [please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), post the text itself and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code). The trailing whitespace will be there, but not obvious, so you could add a note like "Note the trailing whitespace."

Comment: Ok, thank you. I’ll post an answer instead. The code above is an extremely dumbed down version of the actual code, but I appreciate you taking the time to look and comment.